# input data to web site

Tags: web-services, javafx-2

I am working on  a project that is several months old. I need to make it more user friendly. What the program does right now is rendering a little web window where a site is loaded and the user logs in. What I want to do now is to be able to ask the user to give me his/her log in info, then send it from code to the website and then "pressing" submit. So that the users dont have to wait for the webpage to render and the interface is more user friendly.

I am aware that I can do this with Jetty, but the thing is I work with NetBeans and I cannot migrate the project.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use javascript to input the necessary values and submit the form, to execute javascript from java upon page load you do this:

```
webview.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, State oldState, State newState)
    {
        if (ov.getValue() == State.SUCCEEDED)
        {
            webview.getEngine().executeScript("... javascript to submit the form goes here ...");
        }
    }
});
```